# Why persist() method doesn't work in detached state?

Tags: hibernate

I know that we can't use persist() method in detached state.But I don't know the real reason.What is happening behind the picture?

Answer (score 0):

persist method can be use only for new objects (that are not db yet)

u could read more http://blog.xebia.com/jpa-implementation-patterns-saving-detached-entities/